# Recommended route from Ocho Rios to Mandeville: 3 choices

Tags: driving, jamaica

Jamaica is full of lovely friendly people, however, the drivers are, well, scary. That being said, I have a rental car and intend to drive on a Saturday from Ocho Rios to Mandeville. Google shows three routes enumerated by travel time:

- Route 1:  2h 18m through Christiana
- Route 2:  2h 40m A1 (new highway \ tollway?) through Christiana
- Route 3:  2h 36m  A1 to T1 to A2

The distances and times are pretty much all the same, so I would prefer driving on a newer highway without the winding road experienced on the A3 through the mountains.

## Question: Which of the three routes has the best road conditions?

If you have driven the recommended route, please state this in your response.

[image: itineraries]

## UPDATE

Route 3 was recommended by several locals: although there were tolls, road conditions on the toll ways were good in stark contrast to the rest of the system.  OBSERVE THE SPEED LIMITS: construction, falling rocks, DETOURS, are very dangerous on these highways.  ARRIVE ALIVE.